# Open iOS parent application in background

Tags: ios, watchkit

My requirement is to open a parent application in the background from the Watch-kit extension using Objective-C. I am using Xcode8.0. The Watch-kit extension lacks an api method like `openParentApplication`.

Could anyone help me with the available api or sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `openParentApplication` method has been deprecated from watchOS 2.0,  you cannot access the application in background.

To access the parent application from watch app, you can use the `WCSessionDelegate` methods

you can use the tutorial [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchconnectivity-say-hello-to-wcsession/) for reference
 apart from that you may use

```
func sendMessage(_ message: [String : Any], 
replyHandler: (([String : Any]) -> Void)?, 
errorHandler: ((Error) -> Void)? = nil)
```

to communicate with the iphone app instantly if it is alive